# How customize notification in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-firestore

i just implemented firebase cloud messaging pushNotification using Topic messaging. The notification is received but MyFirebaseMessagingService is not working properly. it delivering the message as same as from cloud messaging.

done cloud message function.
create a service name MyFirebaseMessagingService and extend with FirebaseMessagingService.
add service to manifest.

this is my FirebaseMessagingService class.

```
@Override
public void onDeletedMessages() {
    super.onDeletedMessages();
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    String messageTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String clickAction = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
    Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://"+ getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.hollow);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentTitle("New Notification")
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentText(messageTitle);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(clickAction);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) builder.setVibrate(new long[0]);

    int mNotificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(mNotificationId, builder.build());

}
```

My manifest file:-

```
<service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
```

Comment: Read this topic carefully : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple#receive_and_handle_topic_messages

Comment: what do you mean by not working correctly??

Comment: no notification sound, vibration and no banner @Jeeva

Comment: @shah can you show me the code where you are creating your notification channel???

Comment: am using notificationCompact.Builder

Comment: @shah Because you must create the notification channel before posting any notifications on Android 8.0 and higher, you should execute this code as soon as your app starts.

Comment: not working @Jeeva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Sending Cloud Message you also have to subscribe to Topic which you want to receive notification of eg.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("general")
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Subs-Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Subs NOT Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                });
```

In this I have subscribed to topic general and will only receive messages on sent on this topic like this one.

[image: See this pic]

Hope this helps....worked for me!

Comment: This can be done in any activity but must be done before receiving cloud message